# Installing Visual Studio Community Edition with Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, installation, visual-studio-2017

When installing Visual Studio Community, it now comes with Visual Studio 2017.
I don't want that because I am trying to follow a book that uses Visual Studio 2015.
I found this link below.

https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=visual%20studio%202015

But when I click and run Community 2015 with update 3, it seems to be indicating that it will install Visual Studio in the the following default folder:
C\Program File (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0

That tells me that its about to install Visual Studio 14, not 15.
Right?
So how do I get Visual Studio 15 (with Community Edition)?

I also found other answers posted on experts change.
But when I followed the directions, I ran into the exact same problem.
The default directory seems to indicate that it will be installing version 14, not 15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS 2015 is version 14.0, and installs in the location you've indicated. You're making the incorrect assumption that the version correlates with the year in the product name.

Here's the Start Menu shortcut properties information from the install of VS 2015 installed on my machine currently:

[image: VS 2015 shortcut properties image]