# Rust Windows installation - Visual C++ / Visual Studio Community (exit code 5002 )

Tags: c++, windows, rust

I'm installing Rust for Windows using the [rustup (`rustup-init.exe`) 64-bit executable](https://www.rust-lang.org/tools/install)

Running Windows 10 OS Name  Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise Version **10.0.19044 Build 19044**. I have **not** installed Visual Studio successfully before (I have Visual Studio **Code**, but not Visual Studio)...

I get this error at the first step of `rustup-init.exe` when I choose Visual C++ prerequisites:

```
error: failed to install Visual Studio: 
error installing Visual Studio (exit code 5002)
```

I can't find the reason for the error, I checked [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46984585/installing-visual-studio-community-edition-with-visual-studio-2015) and other sites like [this one](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1336632/error-while-installing-visualstudio-error-code-500.html) and [this one](https://community.flexera.com/t5/InstallShield-Knowledge-Base/Build-Error-5002-Product-Configuration-Is-Not-Found-In-The/ta-p/3565/jump-to/first-unread-message)

If I skip that error and continue to install Rust (choosing option `y`), the command suggests I installed successfully,

But when I try to compile, I get a different error (related the failure to install the Visual C++??). This error leads me to [other questions/answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62587035/why-is-msvc-not-installing-or-being-recognized-by-rust), but it feels like the root cause is the (exit code 5002):

```
$ rustc main.rs
error: linking with `link.exe` failed: exit code: 1
```

(When I try to **manually** install the Visual C++ / Visual Studio tools for C/C++ development I get errors like [this one](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/problem-with-visualstudiosetupexe-file-2022/1682912) and [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/751460/visual-studio-setup-installer-does-not-open))

Here is the full output of the original failure to install Visual C++ prerequisites:

```
Rust Visual C++ prerequisites

Rust requires a linker and Windows API libraries but they don't seem to be
available.

These components can be acquired through a Visual Studio installer.

1) Quick install via the Visual Studio Community installer
   (free for individuals, academic uses, and open source).

2) Manually install the prerequisites
   (for enterprise and advanced users).

3) Don't install the prerequisites
   (if you're targeting the GNU ABI).

>1

info: downloading Visual Studio installer
  3.6 MiB /   3.6 MiB (100 %) 534.4 KiB/s in  9s ETA:  0s
info: running the Visual Studio install
info: rustup will continue once Visual Studio installation is complete

error: failed to install Visual Studio: error installing Visual Studio (exit code 5002)
```

Comment: Are you trying to install the [build tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/it/visual-cpp-build-tools/) or [Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/it/vs/features/cplusplus/)?

Comment: Hi @Bob__ , at first I do exactly what `rustup-init.exe`  tells me to do with option 1. That does not seem to work (error 5002). When I try to **manually** do option 1, (to answer your question, I try to use the [build tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/)), I don't get very far...  I run the `vs_BuildTools.exe`...  [I see some files are downloaded... I am prompted for my admin password.... but after I give my password, nothing happens / the installer closes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/751460/visual-studio-setup-installer-does-not-open)

Comment: Could you please also specify in the question what version of the OS are you running and if you already had a previous version of VS installed? Did you *run* the installer as admin?

Comment: OK I added the version of OS (**Version 10.0.19044 Build 19044**), and this is a fresh/new work laptop -- I have Visual Studio **Code** involved but I **have *not* installed Visual Studio yet**.... I think the root problem is when I try to install [Visual Studio, it fails](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/751460/visual-studio-setup-installer-does-not-open) (whether I try to install `vs_BuildTools.exe` or `VisualStudioSetup.exe` or `vs_buildtools__5ce62ee581af4291919124ce435421b5.exe` or etc.... I get the same result...)

Comment: I have no background/understanding with Windows, but I have already seen several times around me people having problem with an overzealous antivirus preventing from installing/running some programs (including Rust). As it is a new computer, may be is there such an antivirus that you could disable **temporarily** just to check if it is the cause of your problem.

Comment: Thanks @prog-fh I guess in my case I just needed admin rights from my work IT ServiceDesk. I appreciate your help!

Comment: @Bob__ or prog-fh if you want to provide an answer suggesting admin rights (as well as any other suggestions you have; like checking versions or other antivirus programs etc) I'll give you accepted answer... Thanks for your help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just needed admin rights (this is a work computer).
So I guess the [unity forum post about admin rights](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1336632/error-while-installing-visualstudio-error-code-500.html) is related.

I thought my credentials had admin rights, but I guess not.

My work IT ServiceDesk helped me -- they entered special credentials (which have elevated permissions I guess), then the Visual Studio Installer opened and prompted me to install as seen in the screenshot below, including individual components:

- MSVC v143 - VS 2022 C++ x64/x86 build tools (Latest)
- Windows 11 SDK (10.0.22000.0)

[image: a screenshot showing rustup-init.exe running on the left and Visual Studio Installer opened on the right, with checkboxes to install Individual Components 1) MSVC v143 - VS 2022 C++ x64/x86 build tools (Latest) and 2) Windows 11 SDK (10.0.22000.0)]

I wish Visual Studio would make clearer error message for my credentials "You do not have sufficient privileges"!